# Open DispForm.aspx on selected list item in a SharePoint list

Tags: list, jquery

Is it possible in a SharePoint list to change the function behind the event 'select item' to open the modal dialog with DispForm.aspx?

So in a list, when you click on a item -> the row gets darkblue, the checkbox gets checked and the ribbon appears. If you want to open the DispForm dialog, you have to click on the linked column. I want to open the DispForm by clicking on whole blue row.

Maybe with JQUERY AOP?

Comment: It is possible. Seen it been done a couple times. But I believe it depends on if it's only for 1 list or several.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the display with checkboxes, I think it is hard to do, because SharePoint already implements its own behaviors. You'll need not only to add yours, but also make sure they don't break your page by interfering with the existing ones.

If you display the list without checkboxes, then there is less SharePoint interaction and you'll be safer, you can then include your own add-ons with JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$('.ms-itmhover').click(function () {
    var aLink = $('a[onclick*="E"', $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)'));
    eval(aLink.attr('onclick').replace('this', 'aLink[0]').replace('return', '//return')); 
})
```

just put the code in the listview page with a contenteditor webpart, it will works!

Answer (score -1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZBF_J1RWis --

check this URL it may be helps.